# How to open specific(ReaderActivity) using shared link in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio project in which there are many articles we have. Articles are opened in ReaderActivity. Reader can share that article on any other social platforms like WhatsApp, Facebook or any other.
My questions are,
1. How can I generate that specific article link to share with unique article ID?
2. If user click on that link, How that specific article can be displayed in App?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: This will help you: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: This is the possible solution but how can I add dynamic article id in the URI? when I share link with id it does not appear as url.

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889744/how-to-pass-data-through-deep-linking

Comment: Thanks Milind, Its done. Only issue now is when I share article id in url for example http://sbc.co.in?artid=+artid url is taken till question mark character only. This is happening only when I share on whatsapp.

Comment: That is totally different issue. You can check with URL being passed

Comment: I solved this issue by adding / before ? Mark.